# php mysql twitter(ish) follow system ... show users not already following

Tags: php, mysql

i am just trying to figure out how to display users i am not currently following in my db's. i have two db's, 'users' & 'friends'. each have a column 'user_id' ... i can show who i am already following, no problem, just can't figure out how to display who i'm NOT following.

here's my code:

```
$get_all_friends = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN friends ON users.user_id = friends.user_id WHERE users.user_id != '".$_GET['user_id']."' GROUP BY users.user_id"; 
$run_all_friends = mysqli_query($con, $get_all_friends); 
while($row_all_friends = mysqli_fetch_array($run_all_friends)) {
```

this is just getting everybody who is a user (i know) i have an if->else built to show who i am following already. i have been stuck on this for days now ... i have tried joining, not joining, if->elses, etc. can't figure it out.

i know that it is probably really simple ... but i just can't seem to grasp it

any help is greatly appreciated!!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nobody chimed in ... no worries ... after doing another query on my site i figured out how it should work. if anybody finds this post and is having the same issue ... here's what i did

```
$get_info = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id != '".$_GET['user_id']."'"; 
$run_info = mysqli_query($con, $get_info); 
while($row_info = mysqli_fetch_array($run_info)) {

$get_friends = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = '".$_GET['user_id']."' AND following_id = '".$row_info['user_id']."'";
$run_friends = mysqli_query($con, $get_friends); 
$row_friends = mysqli_fetch_array($run_friends); 

if($row_friends['following_id'] == '') {
```

essentially all i did was grab everybody who isn't the current user, then grabbed everybody that they are following, and checked to see if they weren't following somebody already it shows their picture and the follow button ... the else from the if statement is just blank. pretty simple once i realized what i was doing wrong.